# Jboss Message Bean (EJB3) - configuration name

Tags: java, configuration, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

Is there a way of specifying the configuration name of a message bean through annotations?
In the `jboss.xml` descriptor you can have different configurations and bind the beans to a particular config:

```
  <message-driven>
     <ejb-name>PushUserAgentBean</ejb-name>                       
     <destination-jndi-name>queue/PushUserAgent</destination-jndi-name>
     <configuration-name>My Custom Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
  </message-driven>
```

Then in `standardjboss.xml` you can specify a custom interceptor stack, etc. for the "My Custom Message Driven Bean" configuration:

```
<container-configuration>
      <container-name>My Custom Message Driven Bean</container-name>
      <call-logging>false</call-logging>
      <invoker-proxy-binding-name>custom-message-driven-bean</invoker-proxy-binding-name>
      <container-interceptors>
        <interceptor>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor</interceptor>
        <interceptor>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor</interceptor>
        <interceptor>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.RunAsSecurityInterceptor</interceptor>
```

Is there a simple way to do the same by using annotations? I don't mind using vendor-specific annotations (ie, non-standard jboss annotations).

Comment: Which version of JBoss, 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. Interceptors are defined in XML only in JBoss. I was sure of that for 4, but looking around in 5 didn't find any changes in that area.